# Como fazer meus próprios comandos e atalhos no Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

O que quero dizer com minha pergunta é que, por exemplo, quando utilizo `sysout` e <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Espaço</kbd> a linha do método `System.out.println();` fica pronta pra eu utilizar, reduzindo meu tempo pra digitar tudo.

Gostaria de saber se tem como fazer meus próprios comandos, utilizando alguma palavra chave e o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Espaço</kbd>, para chamar outros métodos que eu queira. Por exemplo `metodoUm` e <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Espaço</kbd> chama um determinado método que eu queira.

Comment: tem sim, veja esse link: http://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-atalhos-no-eclipse/2150

Comment: É quase o que eu queria Pedro, será que tem como eu criar meus próprios comandos? Os disponíveis no Keys ajudam, mas por exemplo, pensei em digitar "funcaoUm" e Ctrl+Espaço e ele digitaria o texto pra mim correspondente a função que eu quero. 

Imaginei que fosse assim que acontecia com o "sysout", ele apenas digitava um texto que é correspondente a função que eu quero. De forma que eu pudesse modificar esse texto e fazer os meus próprios. Mas seu link me deixou no caminho certo, obrigado!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O nome disso é "Code Template", para cria um vá em Window → Prefences → Java → Editor → Templates, para chegar na seguinte tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clique em "New" para criar seu código do template. Como exemplo, criei um template para automatizar a criação de um atributo e um método para tornar uma classe um Singleton.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código caso queira copiar:

```
private static ${primary_type_name} instancia;
public static ${primary_type_name} getInstancia() {
    if (instancia == null) instancia = new ${primary_type_name}();
    return instancia;
}
```

Agora em um classe recém criada, digite o nome do template aperte <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Espaço</kbd>:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida confirme com o <kbd>Enter</kbd>, sua classe ficará assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que pode-se aumentar e muito o seu poder de template se fizer uso de variáveis, como por exemplo no caso acima que eu usei o `${primary_type_name}`, que substitui a parte do código com o nome da classe. Ao clicar em "Insert Variable" você terá uma lista extensa das variáveis que pode usar.

Comment: Valeu Math! Era isso mesmo, muito obrigado!